# How to configure Artifactory as a cache for Chocolatey? I get 404 when installing packages

Tags: artifactory, chocolatey

Artifactory version: 6.16.2 rev 61602900, **Artifactory Pro** license.

In Artifactory, I have added a REMOTE repository, with the following settings:

- Package Type: **NuGet**
- Repository Key: **chocolatey-remote**
- URL: **https://chocolatey.org/**
- Test: **Successfully connected to server**
- Repository Layout: **nuget-default**
- Include Patterns: ****/***
- NuGet Download Context Path: **api/v2/package**
- NuGet Feed Context Path: **api/v2**
- NuGet v3 Feed URL: (empty)

Screenshots:

[image: Basic]
[image: Advanced]
[image: Replications]

On the host, I have configured Chocolatey sources:

```
choco source add --name=artifactory --source=https://<ARTIFACTORY>/api/nuget/chocolatey-remote --user=***REDACTED*** --password=***REDACTED***
choco source disable --name chocolatey
choco source list
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\vagrant> choco source list     
Chocolatey v0.10.15
artifactory - https://<ARTIFACTORY>/api/nuget/chocolatey-remote (Authenticated)| Priority 0|Bypass Proxy - False|Self-Service - False|Admin Only - False.
chocolatey [Disabled] - https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/ | Priority 0|Bypass Proxy - False|Self-Service - False|Admin Only - False.
```

When running `choco info <PACKAGE>`, I get an expected result:

```
PS C:\Users\vagrant> choco info vlc   
Chocolatey v0.10.15
vlc 3.0.12
 Title: VLC media player | Published: 1/18/2021
 Number of Downloads: 7848809 | Downloads for this version: 252349
 Package url
 Chocolatey Package Source: n/a
 Package Checksum: 'GNbCKwr6nqOoJc/DX/+riBbXyncp1wV3xOAyYTaOgdls+SiKmvUXoIVXUBGTswQMPIc1tKSdYy+KvuVXb4jliQ==' (SHA512)
 Tags: vlc foss cross-platform multimedia audio video mp3 dvd avi media player admin
 Software Site: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/
 Software License: http://www.videolan.org/legal.html
 Summary: VLC Media Player
 Description: VLC is a free and open source cross-platform multimedia player and framework that plays most multimedia files as well as DVD, Audio CD, VCD, and various streaming protocols.
(etc)
```

When I install packages, I get a 404:

```
PS C:\Users\vagrant> choco install vlc
Chocolatey v0.10.15
Installing the following packages:
vlc
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
vlc not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. Not Found
vlc package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
The install of vlc was NOT successful.
vlc not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. Not Found

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - vlc (exited 1) - vlc not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. Not Found
```

This is `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log`:

```
2021-02-04 09:42:36,839 764 [DEBUG] - XmlConfiguration is now operational
2021-02-04 09:42:36,870 764 [INFO ] - ============================================================
2021-02-04 09:42:36,997 764 [INFO ] - Chocolatey v0.10.15
2021-02-04 09:42:36,997 764 [DEBUG] - Chocolatey is running on Windows v 10.0.17763.0
2021-02-04 09:42:36,997 764 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/choco.exe.old".
2021-02-04 09:42:36,997 764 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco.exe.old".
2021-02-04 09:42:37,010 764 [DEBUG] - Command line: "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco.exe" install vlc
2021-02-04 09:42:37,010 764 [DEBUG] - Received arguments: install vlc
2021-02-04 09:42:37,041 764 [DEBUG] - RemovePendingPackagesTask is now ready and waiting for PreRunMessage.
2021-02-04 09:42:37,041 764 [DEBUG] - Sending message 'PreRunMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2021-02-04 09:42:37,041 764 [DEBUG] - [Pending] Removing all pending packages that should not be considered installed...
2021-02-04 09:42:37,088 764 [DEBUG] - Performing validation checks.
2021-02-04 09:42:37,088 764 [DEBUG] - Global Configuration Validation Checks:
2021-02-04 09:42:37,088 764 [DEBUG] -  - Package Exit Code / Exit On Reboot = Checked
2021-02-04 09:42:37,088 764 [DEBUG] - System State Validation Checks:
2021-02-04 09:42:37,088 764 [DEBUG] -  Reboot Requirement Checks:
2021-02-04 09:42:37,088 764 [DEBUG] -  - Pending Computer Rename = Checked
2021-02-04 09:42:37,088 764 [DEBUG] -  - Pending Component Based Servicing = Checked
2021-02-04 09:42:37,088 764 [DEBUG] -  - Pending Windows Auto Update = Checked
2021-02-04 09:42:37,088 764 [DEBUG] -  - Pending File Rename Operations = Checked
2021-02-04 09:42:37,088 764 [DEBUG] -  - Pending Windows Package Installer = Checked
2021-02-04 09:42:37,108 764 [DEBUG] -  - Pending Windows Package Installer SysWow64 = Checked
2021-02-04 09:42:37,108 764 [INFO ] - 2 validations performed. 2 success(es), 0 warning(s), and 0 error(s).
2021-02-04 09:42:37,108 764 [DEBUG] - The source 'https://<ARTIFACTORY>/api/nuget/chocolatey-remote' evaluated to a 'normal' source type
2021-02-04 09:42:37,108 764 [DEBUG] - 
NOTE: Hiding sensitive configuration data! Please double and triple
 check to be sure no sensitive data is shown, especially if copying
 output to a gist for review.
2021-02-04 09:42:37,119 764 [DEBUG] - Configuration: CommandName='install'|
CacheLocation='C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey'|
ContainsLegacyPackageInstalls='True'|
CommandExecutionTimeoutSeconds='2700'|WebRequestTimeoutSeconds='30'|
Sources='https://<ARTIFACTORY>/api/nuget/chocolatey-remote'|
SourceType='normal'|Debug='False'|Verbose='False'|Trace='False'|
Force='False'|Noop='False'|HelpRequested='False'|
UnsuccessfulParsing='False'|RegularOutput='True'|QuietOutput='False'|
PromptForConfirmation='True'|AcceptLicense='False'|
AllowUnofficialBuild='False'|Input='vlc'|AllVersions='False'|
SkipPackageInstallProvider='False'|PackageNames='vlc'|
Prerelease='False'|ForceX86='False'|OverrideArguments='False'|
NotSilent='False'|ApplyPackageParametersToDependencies='False'|
ApplyInstallArgumentsToDependencies='False'|IgnoreDependencies='False'|
AllowMultipleVersions='False'|AllowDowngrade='False'|
ForceDependencies='False'|Information.PlatformType='Windows'|
Information.PlatformVersion='10.0.17763.0'|
Information.PlatformName='Windows Server 2016'|
Information.ChocolateyVersion='0.10.15.0'|
Information.ChocolateyProductVersion='0.10.15'|
Information.FullName='choco, Version=0.10.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=79d02ea9cad655eb'|

Information.Is64BitOperatingSystem='True'|
Information.Is64BitProcess='True'|Information.IsInteractive='False'|
Information.UserName='vagrant'|
Information.UserDomainName='VAGRANT-I7ND05O'|
Information.IsUserAdministrator='True'|
Information.IsUserSystemAccount='False'|
Information.IsUserRemoteDesktop='False'|
Information.IsUserRemote='True'|
Information.IsProcessElevated='True'|
Information.IsLicensedVersion='False'|Information.LicenseType='Foss'|
Information.CurrentDirectory='C:\Users\vagrant'|
Features.AutoUninstaller='True'|Features.ChecksumFiles='True'|
Features.AllowEmptyChecksums='False'|
Features.AllowEmptyChecksumsSecure='True'|
Features.FailOnAutoUninstaller='False'|
Features.FailOnStandardError='False'|Features.UsePowerShellHost='True'|
Features.LogEnvironmentValues='False'|Features.LogWithoutColor='False'|
Features.VirusCheck='False'|
Features.FailOnInvalidOrMissingLicense='False'|
Features.IgnoreInvalidOptionsSwitches='True'|
Features.UsePackageExitCodes='True'|
Features.UseEnhancedExitCodes='False'|
Features.UseFipsCompliantChecksums='False'|
Features.ShowNonElevatedWarnings='True'|
Features.ShowDownloadProgress='True'|
Features.StopOnFirstPackageFailure='False'|
Features.UseRememberedArgumentsForUpgrades='False'|
Features.IgnoreUnfoundPackagesOnUpgradeOutdated='False'|
Features.SkipPackageUpgradesWhenNotInstalled='False'|
Features.RemovePackageInformationOnUninstall='False'|
Features.ExitOnRebootDetected='False'|
Features.LogValidationResultsOnWarnings='True'|
Features.UsePackageRepositoryOptimizations='True'|
Features.ScriptsCheckLastExitCode='False'|
ListCommand.LocalOnly='False'|
ListCommand.IdOnly='False'|ListCommand.IncludeRegistryPrograms='False'|
ListCommand.PageSize='25'|ListCommand.Exact='False'|
ListCommand.ByIdOnly='False'|ListCommand.ByTagOnly='False'|
ListCommand.IdStartsWith='False'|ListCommand.OrderByPopularity='False'|
ListCommand.ApprovedOnly='False'|
ListCommand.DownloadCacheAvailable='False'|
ListCommand.NotBroken='False'|
ListCommand.IncludeVersionOverrides='False'|
UpgradeCommand.FailOnUnfound='False'|
UpgradeCommand.FailOnNotInstalled='False'|
UpgradeCommand.NotifyOnlyAvailableUpgrades='False'|
UpgradeCommand.ExcludePrerelease='False'|
NewCommand.AutomaticPackage='False'| 
NewCommand.UseOriginalTemplate='False'|SourceCommand.Command='unknown'|
SourceCommand.Priority='0'|SourceCommand.BypassProxy='False'|
SourceCommand.AllowSelfService='False'|
SourceCommand.VisibleToAdminsOnly='False'|
FeatureCommand.Command='unknown'|ConfigCommand.Command='unknown'|
ApiKeyCommand.Remove='False'|PinCommand.Command='unknown'|
OutdatedCommand.IgnorePinned='False'|Proxy.BypassOnLocal='True'|
2021-02-04 09:42:37,119 764 [DEBUG] - _ Chocolatey:ChocolateyInstallCommand - Normal Run Mode _
2021-02-04 09:42:37,119 764 [INFO ] - Installing the following packages:
2021-02-04 09:42:37,119 764 [INFO ] - vlc
2021-02-04 09:42:37,119 764 [INFO ] - By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
2021-02-04 09:42:37,166 764 [DEBUG] - Using 'https://<ARTIFACTORY>/api/nuget/chocolatey-remote'.
2021-02-04 09:42:37,338 764 [DEBUG] - - Supports prereleases? 'True'.
2021-02-04 09:42:37,338 764 [DEBUG] - - Is ServiceBased? 'True'.
2021-02-04 09:42:37,544 764 [DEBUG] - Package 'vlc' found on source 'https://<ARTIFACTORY>/api/nuget/chocolatey-remote'
2021-02-04 09:42:37,589 764 [INFO ] - [NuGet] Attempting to resolve dependency 'chocolatey-core.extension (= 1.3.3)'.
2021-02-04 09:42:37,666 764 [ERROR] - vlc not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. Not Found
2021-02-04 09:42:37,666 764 [INFO ] - vlc package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
2021-02-04 09:42:37,666 764 [DEBUG] - No package information as package is null.
2021-02-04 09:42:37,682 764 [DEBUG] - No package information to save as package is null.
2021-02-04 09:42:37,682 764 [DEBUG] - Sending message 'HandlePackageResultCompletedMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2021-02-04 09:42:37,682 764 [ERROR] - The install of vlc was NOT successful.
2021-02-04 09:42:37,682 764 [ERROR] - vlc not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. Not Found
2021-02-04 09:42:37,682 764 [WARN ] -
Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log). 
2021-02-04 09:42:37,682 764 [INFO ] -  
2021-02-04 09:42:37,697 764 [ERROR] - Failures
2021-02-04 09:42:37,697 764 [ERROR] -  - vlc (exited 1) - vlc not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. Not Found
2021-02-04 09:42:37,697 764 [DEBUG] - Sending message 'PostRunMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2021-02-04 09:42:37,732 764 [DEBUG] - Exiting with 1
```

How do I get a working Artifactory cache of Chocolatey without a 404?

I have downloaded the Artifactory logs and grepped for `choco`:

```
$ grep choco *.log
access.log:2021-02-04 15:31:38,164 [DENIED DOWNLOAD] chocolatey-remote-cache:vlc.3.0.12.nupkg  for client : NA / 91.180.197.91.
artifactory.log:2021-02-04 10:57:28,154 [http-nio-8081-exec-992] [INFO ] (o.a.u.r.s.a.c.r.UpdateRepositoryConfigService:64) - Updating repository chocolatey-remote
artifactory.log:2021-02-04 14:36:56,347 [http-nio-8081-exec-1053] [INFO ] (o.a.u.r.s.a.c.r.UpdateRepositoryConfigService:64) - Updating repository chocolatey-remote
request.log:20210204153137|124|REQUEST|91.180.197.91|anonymous|GET|/api/nuget/chocolatey-remote|HTTP/1.0|200|0
request.log:20210204153137|4|REQUEST|91.180.197.91|anonymous|GET|/api/nuget/chocolatey-remote/$metadata|HTTP/1.0|200|0
request.log:20210204153138|128|REQUEST|91.180.197.91|anonymous|GET|/api/nuget/chocolatey-remote/Packages()|HTTP/1.0|200|0
request.log:20210204153138|16|REQUEST|91.180.197.91|anonymous|GET|/api/nuget/chocolatey-remote/Download/vlc/3.0.12|HTTP/1.0|404|0
```

The line `[DENIED DOWNLOAD] chocolatey-remote-cache:vlc.3.0.12.nupkg` looks relevant to the issue, but I'd need an Artifactory expert to help me understand what it means.

I ran the `choco` command exactly like @yahavi in answer below:

```
PS C:\Users\vagrant> choco install vlc --source=https://<ARTIFACTORY>/api/nuget/chocolatey-remote --user=***REDACTED*** --password=***REDACTED***
Chocolatey v0.10.15
Installing the following packages:
vlc
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
vlc not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. Not Found
vlc package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
The install of vlc was NOT successful.
vlc not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. Not Found

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - vlc (exited 1) - vlc not installed. An error occurred during installation:
 The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. Not Found
```

As a sanity check, I also did `choco install vlc --source=https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/` and that worked. This rules out any issue on Chocolatey's side, it's most definitely an issue with Artifactory.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this issue, I noticed that the only URL mentioned in Chocolatey's [FAQ](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/faqs#what-is-the-default-package-source-repository-url-community-feed-url) was https://community.chocolatey.org/
Changing the config to that fixed it for me.

I didn't check to see if there were other supported URLs, it might depend what package you are trying to get? The config I inherited was set to:
https://www.chocolatey.org and I noticed yours was set to just https://chocolatey.org and neither worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the `NuGet v3 Feed URL` to be the default value: `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`.

We use Artifactory as a caching mechanism for Chocolatey in our [tests](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/blob/v1.44.0/appveyor.yml#L74).
The usage is not exactly like yours, since we add the connection details in the install command:

```
choco install vlc -s <jfrog-url>/api/nuget/chocolatey-remote -u <username> -p <password>
```

To get more information, you're welcome to read my blog:
https://jfrog.com/blog/artifactory-as-a-caching-mechanism-for-package-managers/

Comment: I've set the v3 feed to the default value, same result: 404. When I use the source explicitly on the commandline as in your usage, I also get a 404. Your blog post was actually one of the documentation I read before I started configuring this, together with other pages on the JFrog website. Is there some really, really low level debug logging I can check in Artifactory to figure out what is happening?

Comment: I'll update the question with things I found in the Artifactory logs.

Comment: I'm afraid I'll have to downvote your answer, because it doesn't solve the problem, and giving source explicitly on commandline or using Chocolatey's source list, doesn't make any difference from the point of view of Artifactory: the request is identical.

Comment: Could this be a bug in our Artifactory Pro 6.16.2 rev 61602900 and is it fixed in a more recent releast? If so, a link to a changelog will help me to ask IT to upgrade Artifactory.

Comment: On https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Release+Notes I found a few NuGet related issues that were solved in Artifactory 6.19.1: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-21846, https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-21838. Could any of these, or others, be related?